# how to prevent java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out?

Tags: java, jdbc, socket-timeout-exception

can any body explain java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out 
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198) 
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180) 
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391) 
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:289) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.(SharedSocket.java:250) 
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:297)
```

Comment: This is a database connection error. Can you do a telnet to your database server and port?

Comment: yes  i trying to access remote system .so i got Connection timed out  can you give me the solution for me

Comment: Can you try to ping the server? Another problem can be SQL server requires you to enable TCP/IP protocol manually if you want to connect from networked systems.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the driver tried to open connection to that IP on that port, but there was <strike>no one listening on that port</strike>, so no one answered hence the "connection timed out" message.

As Arunn P Johny suggested, if you open up a command line and run

```
telnet localhost 4545
```

and it responds like this

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

this means that no one is listening. E.g. Trying to open a socket(database connection) on that port will result in connection timed out exception. (Port 4545 was chosen because there isn't anything listening on it on my computer)

If it responds with anything else e.g.

```
telnet localhost 3306

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It means that the port is open and that the exception won't be thrown. (There is MySQL  listening on 3306 on my computer).

<strike>Most probably the IP and port in your database [connection string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_string)(see here for [reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)) is wrong, e.g. set to some port that no database is listening on.</strike>

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102489/679982) and an explanation for [HTTP Error 408 Request timeout](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html) (it is the same error).

EDIT:

I initially gave a wrong answer (as EJP pointed out). Both errors happen on TCP level while establishing connection:

- `Connection refused` means that there is no one listening on the given port
- `Connection timeout` means that the connection couldn't be established, or, as stated by EJP that connection attempt timed out.

Suppose you have the following line in Java, eventually JDBC driver does (something like) this at some point:

```
Socket s = new Socket(IP,PORT);
```

*Before* this line is executed the (TCP) connection is *closed*. *After* this line gets executed, and no exception gets thrown, the connection is *established* (as stated in [apidoc for constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int))). *While* this line is executing this is what actually happens (it is called *TCP three-way handshake*):

[image: TCP threeway handshake]

Let's review two possible situations.

First, let's say that the IP is reachable (e.g. `ping IP` from the command line starts printing response times to console) but there is not process listening on the PORT. The three-way handshake will occur as drawn but as soon the connection gets *established* the server won't find any of his processes listening on that port and will initiate closing of the connection immediatley - `Connection refused` will  be thrown.

*This is the only possible outcome for this exception*.

Now, let's assume the IP isn't reachable. The client will send the *connection request* but will never receive *connection granted*. After a given period of time (*timeout*) has passed the `Connection timeout` will be thrown. Consider the following code:

```
    String reachableIP = "127.0.0.1";
    String unreachableIP = "10.192.0.1";
    int connTimeout = 1000;
    long duration = 0;        
    try {
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis();            
        new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress(unreachableIP, 3306), connTimeout);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - duration;           
        System.out.println("connect attempt duration measured in ms:" + duration);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

outputs:

```
connect attempt duration measured in ms:1009
connect timed out
```

This is also stated in [apidoc for connect method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)). So, this exception gets thrown if the destination IP is unreachable. However, reasons for *unreachability* of a computer on a network can be numerous. The first thing that comes to my mind is that the host is turned off, or to rephrase EJP's comment:

*There are numerous causes, like the backlog queue filling up, or network connectivity problems that could lead to this exception.*

Comment: 'Connection timed out'  doesn't mean no one was listening. That would cause 'connection refused', as in your own test. It means the connection attempt timed out, which could have a number of causes, like the backlog queue filling up, or network connectivity problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to ping the sql server, then this might be a problem with the TCP/IP configuration in the sql server instance.

You can refer the [this question on how to enable TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138172/enable-tcp-ip-remote-connections-to-sql-server-express-already-installed-databas) also refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx) articles from Microsoft.

> 1. Start SQL Server Configuration Manager. Click Start, point to All Programs, and click Microsoft SQL Server. Click Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
> 2. In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand SQL Server Network Configuration.
> 3. In the console pane, click Protocols for .
> 4. In the details pane, right-click TCP/IP, and then click Enable.
> 5. In the console pane, click SQL Server Services.
> 6. In the details pane, right-click SQL Server (), and then click Restart, to stop and restart the SQL Server service.

Answer (score 0):

in most of the times the connection time out problem occurs due to proxy of your internet.
make sure, you have provided all proxy setting in your IDE's network settings as well as your default system proxy settings.

if problem, still persists you must try with no proxy connection...hope it helps